# Alternatives to "eval" for ActiveSupport date parsing

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, activesupport

My script currently accepts ActiveSupport date string as a command line argument:

```
my_script --mindate 1.day
```

Inside my script I am using eval to store it into my config

```
MyScript.configuration.min_date = eval(min_date_string)
```

I understand that this is extremely dodgy and insecure as anything can be passed to eval, but what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want time durations? I suppose you could use [chronic_duration](https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration).

```
 my_script --mindate "1 day"
 MyScript.configuration.min_date = ChronicDuration.parse(min_date_string)
```

But since it's natural language heuristics, it becomes not entirely well defined exactly what sorts of strings it will recognize. But it will do fancy things like "1 day and four hours".

Or you could write your own very simple parser/interpreter for the argument. Just split on a space (for "1 day" type of input) or a period (for "1.day") type of input. Recognize a few words in the second position ("hour", "minute" "day", "month", "year"), translate them to seconds, multiply the number by the translated-to-seconds word. A dozen or so lines of ruby probably.

Or you could even take advantage of the ActiveSupport feature that supports things like "1.day" to make it even easier.

```
  str = "11 hours"
  number, unit = str.split(' ')
  number.to_i.send(unit)
```

That would let the command line user send any method they want to a number. I'm not sure it matters. For that matter, I'm not sure if the original `eval` really matters or not -- but I agree with you it's bad practice. For that matter, probably so is `send` on user input, although not quite as bad.

Or you could just make them send in the raw number of seconds and calulcate it themselves.

```
my_script --mindate 86400
```

You realize `1.day` just ends up being converted to the number of seconds in a standard day, right? I'm not sure why you're calling a number of seconds "mindate", but that's your business!

**edit** Or yet another alternative, make them do:

```
my_script --mindays 2 --minhours 4 --minminutes 3
```

or something.

Answer (score 0):

How is your script being called?  Is this always going to be called by a user with an account on whatever machine is running it?  Is this somehow going to get called by a web service, or in a way that someone without access to the machine would be able to call it remotely with their own arguments?

If it's only going to be called by users, and those users already have access to the `ruby` command or `irb`, then you're not enabling them to do anything that they can't already do by calling eval.

If it's called remotely, you should probably not be using eval.  Or, a quick and dirty solution could be to match patterns that you will eval with a regex.  Something like `/^[0-9]+(\.[a-z_0-9]+){,2}$/` would ensure that it's within 2 method calls of a Fixnum literal before evaluating.

Comment: I agree with you it's probably not that big a deal. But probably better safe than sorry. Sure, someone with command line access can already execute any ruby they want. But then you write your utility, and then later you end up using it somehow, maybe shelling out to it, such that it ends up being called with an argument passed in from _remote_ user input, oops you just gave remote user RCE, and you'd probably never realize it, since it goes through a couple steps, and you forgot that the arg to the command line ended up eval'd.